# Circular reference and destructor in Python

Tags: python, destructor

I'm reading an article saying that the presence of **del** method and circular reference prevents the object from being garbage collected. Here is a simple testing code

```
class FooType():
    def __init__(self, id, parent):
        self.id = id
        self.parent = parent
        print('Foo', self.id, 'born')

    def __del__(self):
        print('Foo', self.id, 'died')


class BarType():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.foo = FooType(id, self)
        print('Bar', self.id, 'born')

    def __del__(self):
        print('Bar', self.id, 'died')


b = BarType(12)
```

As I can figure out, Bartype calls FooType during initialization, which in turn keeps a reference of Bartype. A simple circular reference. I expect the interpreter to exit without garbage collect. However, the output of this code shows that the object has been destructed before exiting.

```
Foo 12 born
Bar 12 born
Foo 12 died
Bar 12 died
```

The only reason I can think of is that CPython may have some updates(my version is 3.4). Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: Yes, the behavior was changed in 3.4.  See [PEP 442](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/).

Comment: @BrenBarn Oh now I see the reason. Thank you for pointing this out to me!